# Circle CI CLI Hangs at Checkout Step

Tags: circleci

I am using the Circle CI CLI to try to reproduce the remote CI environment. I keep getting stuck at the checkout step. No errors, just hangs there.

I tried it with `--skip-checkout=false` and it asks for my password, and then same thing...just hangs.

```
====>> Checkout code
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
mkdir -p /home/circleci/app && cp -r /tmp/_circleci_local_build_repo/. /home/circleci/app



    aliases:
    - &ecr-login
        name: ecr-login
        command: |
        export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}
        export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_KEY}
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev
        sudo pip install awscli
        sudo $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)

    - &ecr-login-cypress
        name: ecr-login-cypress
        command: |
        export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}
        export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_KEY}
        apt-get update
        apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev
        pip install awscli
        $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)

    - &save_cache
        paths:
        # we need both yarn cache and node_modules
        # also make sure that working dir is app
        - ~/.cache/yarn
        - node_modules
        key: yarn-packages-v4-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}

    - &restore_cache
        name: Restore Yarn Package Cache
        keys:
            # only restores cache if the yarn file is the same
            - yarn-packages-v4-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}

    - &pull_site
        name: Pull from Docker
        command: docker pull "241884713626.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/website:latest"

    - &start_app
        name: Start App
        command: |
            docker run -td  -e DOCKER=1 \
                            -e CIRCLE_NODE_TOTAL=$CIRCLE_NODE_TOTAL \
                            -e CIRCLE_NODE_INDEX=$CIRCLE_NODE_INDEX \
                            -e NODE_ENV=development \
                            --name="app" \
                            --expose 5006 \
                            "241884713626.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/website:latest" \
                            sh -c "tail -f /dev/null"

    - &copy_app
        name: Copy Local app
        command: docker cp . app:/usr/src/app

    - &build_site
        name: Build Site
        command: |
            docker exec -t app sh -c "gulp clean && gulp buildonly &&  yarn generate-assets"

    - &start_site
        name: Start App
        command: |
            docker exec -td app sh -c "gulp server --docker --local"

    - &install_deps
        name: Install Dev Yarn deps
        command:  yarn install --production=false

    version: 2
    jobs:
    clone_and_install:
        <<: *defaults
        working_directory: ~/app

        steps:
        - checkout
        - restore_cache: *restore_cache
        - run: *install_deps
        - save_cache: *save_cache

    cypress_tests:
        docker:
        - image: circleci/node:9.11.1-browsers

        parallelism: 4

        working_directory: ~/app
        steps:
        - setup_remote_docker:
            docker_layer_caching: true
        - run: *ecr-login

        - checkout
        # - restore_cache: *restore_cache

        - run: *pull_site
        - run: *start_app
        - run: *start_site
        - run: *copy_app
        - run: *build_site
        - run:
            name: Install Cypress
            command: sudo apt-get -y install xvfb libgtk2.0-0 libnotify-dev libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 libasound2 && yarn cypress install
        - run:
            name: Run tests
            command: yarn run cypress:ci --ci-build-id ${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}
        - store_artifacts:
            path: /usr/src/app/cypress/videos
        - store_artifacts:
            path: /usr/src/app/cypress/screenshots
        - store_artifacts:
            path: /usr/src/app/cypress/snapshots
```

Comment: The `checkout` step, when run locally, does a copy of files. I suspect the copy is taking a long time. It may be slow if you're using a VM to run docker, or the docker root is on a slow disk.

Comment: do you know why it's this incredibly slow though? It takes over 10 minutes to copy 400MB. That's slower than my internet speed even...My disk is magnitudes faster

Comment: The `checkout` step will do a full clone, which most people do not need. You could try copying the script (visible in a CI run) and then do a shallow clone, just to get the project state at the checkout hash.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it runs...just takes > 10 minutes. I'm not sure what's causing the extreme slowness, but when I deleted my local node_modules it was slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Since the checkout step will just clone the entire local directory (not just what you checkout with git), you need to watch out for hidden and untracked files.

Make sure you `rm -rf ./node_modules` before running the job.
If that's not enough, also clean up your git repo, by removing un-necessary local branches, and run `git gc`. That will make the `.git` 
dir smaller.